# java process shows huge RSS consumption than expect in aarch64

Tags: java, arm64, memory-consumption

Recently I deployed a java process in aarch64, but found the RSS consumption is much more higher than deploy it on x86 environment. From the jvm args, the process can only allocate for about 7 GiB memory including heap and native, but the RSS of process reached for about 10GiB, and got killed by oom-killer.
Here is an example, from /proc/$PID/status found VmRSS is 8511424KB, but from java Native Memory Tracing, it committed 2389438KB at the same time, where were this huge consumption from? How to troubleshoot further?
[image]

---

Here is some detailed information.

- jvm : **Hotspot openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04**
- jvm args : {-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent;-XX:+UseG1GC;-XX:-UseBiasedLocking;-XX:-G1UseAdaptiveIHOP;-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15;-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4M;-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError;-Djdk.nio.maxCachedBufferSize=1048576;**-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1024m**;**-Xmx1024m**;**-Xms1024m**;}
- using **jemalloc-5.3.0** as memory allocator
- arm : **Linux iZ2zeia8go4ym9efunf4tqZ 4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.aarch64**
- os : **CentOS8.4.2105**

----------

Using strace to trace system calls of JVM Finalizer thread, the result shows that Finalizer allocated huge size memory(1G) in arm than x86(8M) at the beginning of thread start.

arm-strace-log-of-jvm-Finalizer-thread:

```
10:41:39.722125 set_robust_list(0xffffa053da50, 24) = 0
10:41:39.722211 mmap(NULL, 536870912, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfffd20000000
10:41:39.722298 mmap(NULL, 536870912, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfffd00000000
10:41:39.722330 sched_getaffinity(111949, 32, [0, 1, 2, 3]) = 8
10:41:39.722367 sched_getaffinity(111949, 32, [0, 1, 2, 3]) = 8
10:41:39.722397 getpid()                = 111940
10:41:39.722421 gettid()                = 111949
10:41:39.722443 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [QUIT], 8) = 0
10:41:39.722472 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [HUP INT ILL BUS FPE SEGV USR2 TERM], NULL, 8) = 0
10:41:39.722501 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [QUIT], NULL, 8) = 0
10:41:39.722529 futex(0xffff201a0780, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
10:41:39.722558 futex(0xffff201a4780, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
10:41:39.722631 futex(0xffff201a4728, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
10:41:39.722663 mmap(0xffffa0340000, 196608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xffffa0340000
10:41:39.722704 mprotect(0xffffa0340000, 196608, PROT_NONE) = 0
10:41:39.722741 prctl(PR_SET_NAME, "Finalizer") = 0
10:41:39.722807 pread64(5, "\312\376\272\276\0\0\0007\1\32\n\0<\0\260\t\0\4\0\261\t\0\4\0\262\7\0\263\7\0\264\7"..., 6080, 51205510) = 6080
10:41:39.722969 futex(0xffff201a4380, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
10:41:39.733568 futex(0xffff201a4328, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
10:41:39.733620 futex(0xffff201a4384, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
10:41:41.179815 futex(0xffff201a4328, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
10:41:41.179886 futex(0xffff201a4380, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
10:41:41.760317 futex(0xffff201a4328, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
10:41:41.760372 futex(0xffff201a4384, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
10:41:42.773671 futex(0xffff201a4328, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
10:41:42.776444 futex(0xffff201a4380, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
10:41:43.885320 futex(0xffff201a4328, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
10:41:43.885380 futex(0xffff201a4384, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
10:41:55.499245 futex(0xffff201a4328, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
10:41:55.500216 futex(0xffff201a5780, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
10:41:55.500712 futex(0xffff201a4380, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
11:08:17.920555 futex(0xffff201a4328, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
11:08:17.920755 futex(0xffff201a4384, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=999880}) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
11:08:17.920815 futex(0xffff201a4328, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
11:08:17.928742 futex(0xffff201a4380, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
12:08:17.944661 futex(0xffff201a4328, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
12:08:17.947491 futex(0xffff201a5f80, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
12:08:17.949910 futex(0xffff201a4384, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=999120}) = 0
12:08:17.950087 futex(0xffff201a4328, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
12:08:17.950171 futex(0xffff201a4380, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
12:08:17.950258 futex(0xffff201a4328, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
12:08:17.950356 futex(0xffff201a4384, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=999760}) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
12:08:17.950443 futex(0xffff201a4328, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
12:08:17.950511 futex(0xffff201a4380, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
12:08:17.950594 futex(0xffff201a4328, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
12:08:17.950674 futex(0xffff201a4384, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=999880}) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
12:08:17.950756 futex(0xffff201a4328, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
12:08:17.950824 futex(0xffff201a4380, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
12:08:17.950894 futex(0xffff201a4328, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
12:08:17.950961 futex(0xffff201a4384, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
12:08:17.951021 futex(0xffff201a4328, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
```

x86-strace-log-of-jvm-Finalizer-thread:

```
10:07:40.586689 set_robust_list(0x7efca55ff9e0, 24) = 0
10:07:40.586764 mmap(NULL, 2097152, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x7efca52ff000
10:07:40.586832 munmap(0x7efca52ff000, 2097152) = 0
10:07:40.586884 mmap(NULL, 4190208, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x7efca5100000
10:07:40.586932 munmap(0x7efca5100000, 1048576) = 0
10:07:40.586983 munmap(0x7efca5400000, 1044480) = 0
10:07:40.587460 mmap(NULL, 2097152, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x7efca5000000
10:07:40.587509 sched_getaffinity(7573, 32, [0, 1, 2, 3]) = 32
10:07:40.587957 sched_getaffinity(7573, 32, [0, 1, 2, 3]) = 32
10:07:40.588011 gettid()                = 7573
10:07:40.588062 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [QUIT], 8) = 0
10:07:40.588116 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [HUP INT ILL BUS FPE SEGV USR2 TERM], NULL, 8) = 0
10:07:40.588164 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [QUIT], NULL, 8) = 0
10:07:40.588214 futex(0x7efcc529c854, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x7efcc529c850, FUTEX_OP_SET<<28|0<<12|FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT<<24|0x1) = 1
10:07:40.588265 futex(0x7efcc52a0854, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL) = 0
10:07:40.588393 futex(0x7efcc52a0828, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
10:07:40.588435 mmap(0x7efca54ff000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efca54ff000
10:07:40.588484 mprotect(0x7efca54ff000, 16384, PROT_NONE) = 0
10:07:40.588529 prctl(PR_SET_NAME, "Finalizer") = 0
10:07:40.588645 pread64(4, "\312\376\272\276\0\0\0007\1\32\n\0<\0\260\t\0\4\0\261\t\0\4\0\262\7\0\263\7\0\264\7"..., 6080, 52275686) = 6080
10:07:40.588850 futex(0x7efcc52a0554, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL) = 0
10:07:40.601446 futex(0x7efcc52a0528, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
10:07:40.601511 futex(0x7efcc52a0554, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 3, NULL) = 0
10:07:42.354182 futex(0x7efcc52a0528, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
10:07:42.354292 futex(0x7efcc52a0554, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 5, NULL) = 0
10:07:43.080472 futex(0x7efcc52a0528, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
10:07:43.080599 futex(0x7efcc52a0554, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 7, NULL) = 0
10:07:44.289658 futex(0x7efcc52a0528, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
10:07:44.289730 futex(0x7efcc52a0554, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 9, NULL) = 0
10:07:44.289864 futex(0x7efcc52a0528, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
10:07:44.289943 futex(0x7efcc52a0554, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 11, NULL) = 0
10:07:45.617260 futex(0x7efcc52a0528, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
10:07:45.618040 futex(0x7efcc52a0554, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 13, NULL) = 0
10:27:49.668478 futex(0x7efcc52a0528, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
10:27:49.668599 futex(0x7efcc52a1854, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x7efcc52a1850, FUTEX_OP_SET<<28|0<<12|FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT<<24|0x1) = 1
10:27:49.668811 futex(0x7efcc52a0554, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 15, NULL
```